# mongo BulkWriteOperation with upsert option doesn't return upserted entries for updates

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I'm using `mongo-java-driver-3.0.4` jar in my application. My mongodb version is `3.2.10`.

Basically what i'm trying is to do a bulk write operation to create or insert documents. I'm trying this with the `upsert` option. What i notice is the following:

- Whenever new documents are created, the `BulkWriteResult#getUpserts()` returns me the `List<BulkWriteUpsert>` with the created documents.
- However when i'm trying to update existing documents, `BulkWriteResult#getUpserts()` returns me an empty array.

I use the following snippet:

```
DBCollection coll = getDBCollection();
BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
for() { //in a loop to populate the bulkWriteOperation
  DBObject obj = getDbObject();
  bulkWriteOperation.find(getQueryObject()).upsert().replaceOne(obj);
}

BulkWriteResult result = bulkWriteOperation.execute(writeConcern)
```

This looks to be a bug in the driver but i'm not sure, since as per the [api](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteResult.html#getUpserts--) i see this description:

> Gets an unmodifiable list of upserted items, or the empty list if
>   there were none.

which i understood as get the list of items which are either updated or inserted.

Answer (score 3):

The upserts will only be populated when the upsert resulted in an insert. Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates:

```
public class BulkUpsertTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoClient m = new MongoClient("localhost");
        DBCollection coll = m.getDB("test").getCollection("bulkUpsertTest");
        coll.drop(); // drop the collection so that first iteration is insert
        test(coll); // first iteration insert
        test(coll); // second iteration update
    }

    public static void test(DBCollection coll) {
        BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
          DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", i);
          DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("x", i);
          bulkWriteOperation.find(query).upsert().replaceOne(obj);
        }

        BulkWriteResult result = bulkWriteOperation.execute();
        List<BulkWriteUpsert> upserts = result.getUpserts();

        System.out.println("result: " + result);

        if (upserts != null) {
            System.out.println("Upserts size: " + upserts.size());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Upserts is null");
        }
    }


}
```

**Output** (note differences in counts for `matchedCount`, `modifiedCount`, and `upserts` for the 2 cases:

```
result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=0, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=0, upserts=[BulkWriteUpsert{index=0, id=0}, BulkWriteUpsert{index=1, id=1}, BulkWriteUpsert{index=2, id=2}]}
Upserts size: 3
result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=3, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=3, upserts=[]}
Upserts size: 0
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet. But i'm trying to understand why `getUpserts` returns empty when an update happens. If that is the expected behavior, then to me `BulkWriteResult.getUpserted()` is not the right function name.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. See http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteResult.html. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/#BulkWriteResult.upserted specifies it more precisely by using "inserted" rather than "upserted".

Comment: Ok so that documentation is more accurate vs the javadoc which says `Gets an unmodifiable list of upserted items, or the empty list if there were none.`

Comment: So then there's not way for someone to get the list of id's which were updated but not modified?

Comment: Generally when you're upserting, your query should be based on the _id or some other unique key. So the list of ids would already be known by the calling client.

Comment: So in our case we're upserting based off a query. So if the query didn't find any match then the insert/update will not happen for that document. Which is why i was hoping i could use the `getUpserted` to figure out which one didnt go through.

Comment: please ignore my above comment

Answer (score 2):

From java [docs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteUpsert.html) for `BulkWriteUpsert`

> Represents an upsert request in a bulk write operation that resulted
>   in an insert. It contains the index of the upsert request in the
>   operation and the value of the _id field of the inserted document.

So it contains the write operations that resulted in insert but not update.

In case of updates this property may be relevant to you `BulkWriteResult.nModified`

More information here on [BulkWriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i'm not actually using `BulkWriteUpsert`. Or do you mean that class is resolved to when the actual `.execute()` runs?

Comment: Np. `BulkWriteResult.getUpserts()` returns `List<BulkWriteUpsert>`.`BulkWriteResult` is the main write result class with different values set based on bulk operations. My answer was trying to explain what type of element that list has and what it holds.

Comment: `Upsert` is just about an operation which resulted in insert of document in update scenario. Its similar to insert but just in update scenario with query filter.

Comment: So then there's not way for someone to get the list of id's which were updated but not modified?

Comment: You query will always result in either new document or updating document.  When you say not modified what scenario are you talking about ?

Comment: you're right, that scenario will not happen. Initially i wasn't using the `upsert()` option. So i had the scenario where i want to bulk update  documents based off a query. So if the query didn't find a match it wouldn't update that document. However the response from `bulkWriteOperation.execute` doesn't give me back anything which will tell me which exact documents were updated. Which is why i wanted to use `.upsert`, but now i realize i can't use `upsert` since i dont want to insert if the query didnt find a match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141596/discussion-between-user320550-and-veeram).